# Generate captchas with its solution in the name

Tags: captcha

I want to try to *solve captchas with an artificial intelligence*. Therefore I need to **generate captchas with the solution in its name**.

I thought of captchas like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Does anyone of you has an idee how to generate such captchas?

*For your info: Creating an artifical intelligence which can solve such captchas is a challenge for me - i'm NOT interesed in publish it or doing any bad things with it.*

With best regards,

Philipp

Answer (score 0):

I do not have much idea about creating systems which generate Captchas from a given name. Yes, you can Convolutional Neural networks for identifying captchas. Then you can follow these steps.

1. Create a Convolutional neural network. Refer [here](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/machine-learning-is-fun-part-3-deep-learning-and-convolutional-neural-networks-f40359318721).
2. Get a dataset which contains a number of captchas with their hidden names.
3. Train the network over the dataset.
4. Make predictions.

Hope it helped you.